# HTML table populated through sqlite/flask app showing raw code not formatted code

Tags: html, sqlite, flask

I created a sqlite database containing a bunch of formatted html code. When I try to send it to a HTML table the code is coming in as HTML source code and not being formatted. Yet if I copy and paste the same code one at a time in table cells it formats. How to get code to format when it's coming in from flask/sqlite? I'm getting the table to load I just want the 'formatteddax' column to have the formatting applied. thanks

**how the data looks now:**
[image]

**html file**

```
<table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Measure</th>
                    <th>Formatted DAX</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for measure in measures %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ measure[0] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ measure[2] }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**app.py file**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///C:\\Users\\xyz\\Documents\\DAX-formatter\\dax2.sqlite')
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect = True)

session = Session(engine)

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET'])
def daxionary():
        cursor = engine.execute('SELECT Measure, formatteddax FROM daxionary2')
        return render_template('daxionary.html', measures=cursor.fetchall())
```

Comment: try using `safe` filter. In your template do it like: `{{ measure[0] | safe }}`

Comment: ^ This. @NalinDobhal please add as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to mark your HTML safe by using `safe` filter.

```
{% for measure in measures %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ measure[0] | safe }}</td>
        <td>{{ measure[2] | safe }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Further read [Controlling Autoescaping](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#controlling-autoescaping)

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.